# Spring-boot : Return custom pojo object with HQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

Say I have these 3 entities

```
@Entity
public class Student {
  @Id
  @Column
  long studentId;

  @Column
  String name;
}


@Entity
public class Exam{
  @Id
  @Column
  long examId;
}

@Entity
public class StudentExam {
  @Id
  @Column
  long studentExamId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn("student_id")
  Student student;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn("exam_id")
  Exam exam;

  @Column
  int score;
}
```

And I have this pojo class

```
public class StudentExamDTO {
  ExamDTO exam;
  StudentDTO student;
  int bestScore;
}
```

Where ExamDTO and StudentDTO are simple non entities models. And best score is the best a student has obtained in the given exam.
What I want is a simple request to return directly the ExamStudentDTO using Spring-Boot repository interface

```
public interface ExamRepository extends JpaRepository<ExamStudent, Long> {

  @Query("select new StudentExam(...)  ..")
  Object getStudentExam(@Param("examId")long examId, @Param("studentId")long studentId);

}
```

Is there a way I can access the data like doing Object["column"] ? If so, is it possible to fetch the result directly on the StudentExamDTO class ?

Comment: Which issue do you have?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to to directly return the result data of a query into a custom pojo class. A query that contains aggregate functions

Comment: create a view in the DB and map the view to  the Entity. Then query the view with the Repository.